# How to use a C++ class from Rust?

Tags: c++, class, rust, ffi

I have a C++ app and Rust dynamic library that is used by the App.

I need using app C++ class `Core` from my Rust library.

The C++ class:

```
class Core {
public:
    void printMessage(const char* text, const int length) {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

In Rust library I have defined the opaque struct `Core`:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct Core {}

impl Core {
    // How to declare functions?
}
```

And I try to initialize and use the instance from the app:

```
let mut core: 'static Option<*const Core> = None;

// This func will be called from the app
pub extern "C" fn init(core_instance: <??? *const Core ???> ) {
    core = core_instance;
}


fn foo() {
    if let Some(core) = core {
        core.printMessage("Hello", 5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Rust doesn't have a direct ABI with C++ you're probably looking for something like [cxx](https://cxx.rs/) (haven't used it but it's the first such tool that pops up)

Answer (score 2):

I partly solved this issue. Instead of try loading the C++ class I used a callback.

The Rust library:

```
type FnCallback = extern "C" fn(*const c_uchar, c_int);

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn event(print_message: FnCallback) {
    let message = CString::new("Hello")
        .unwrap()
        .to_bytes()
        .as_ptr();
    
    print_message(message, 5);
}
```

The C++ app:

```
void printMessage(const unsigned char* text, const int length) {
    // ...
}

typedef void (*FnPrintMessage)(const unsigned char*, const int);

typedef void (*FnEvent)(FnPrintMessage);

void main() {
    // Init library
    FnEvent fnEvent = LoadLibraryFunc();
    
    // Invoke event func from rust dylib
    fnEvent(printMessage);
}
```